# Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception: Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, email, cron

I am running `magento 1.9.1 website on AWS EC2 Ubuntu` machine. Customer registration emails are going out but transnational emails are not going.

I configure `SMTP` by `AWS SES` service with `SMTP Pro` extension. I got below error on email sending

```
2017-07-29T06:54:31+00:00 ERR (3): 
Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception: Must issue a STARTTLS command first
 in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(91): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send('sharma.sdaf...', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(83): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1369): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

`cron_schedule` table is also empty

Comment: set Queue Usage to never to SMPT Pro and try

Comment: Yes, I have set that to `never`. I tried with `custom smtp` and `SES` both methods, but same result.

Comment: Could you please check the Apache error log

Comment: for what should I look into log?

Answer (score 0):

> Described config is functional, for viewing changes in scripts is
>   needed to turn off Magento compiler an clean /includes/folder.
>
> There is changed email function supporting Google Gmail or Google
>   Apps:
>
> 1 copy file "**app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**" to
>   "**app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**"
>
> 2 In file app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/**Template.php** change
>   function:

```
public function getMail()
{
    if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
    $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
    $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
    $config = array(
              'port' => $my_smtp_port,
              'auth' => 'login',
              'ssl' => 'tls',
              'username' => 'youremail@gmail.com',
              'password' => 'Abc'
              );
     $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host,$config);
     Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);         





        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    }
    return $this->_mail;
}
```

> Disable compiler, rename folder /includes/ in magento root and clear
>   cache

Please check following post related for same issue,Hope it's helpful for you.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265792/4373980
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453718/4373980
>
> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76838/18639
>
> Another solution try this:-
>
> **> Try to disabled TLS Support or add valid certificate into smtp mail
>   program.**